How can I have either just ONE hyphen OR comma delimited strings in a regex expression
I tried this
^[-A-Za-z0-9]+(,[-A-Za-z0-9]+)*$ 

and it's perfect for comma delimited strings but I'm not able to create an expression that should give me either a SINGLE hyphen or a comma delimited list of strings.
I tried regex generator online as well but nothing to my avail.

Either of the two: ^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[,-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$ or ^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=([,-])?)(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$

Didn't work either of them.

Then either your requirements are unclear, or you are using the pattern in a wrong way.

I don't understand what you're looking for. Please give examples of input and desired results.

Yes, please. Examples, both positive and negative, would be awesome.

Do the items in your lists contain hyphens? Your current pattern suggests that they do.

Do you mean either comma or hyphen delimited but not hybrid (e.g. aaa-bbb,ccc)? If that's the case, you may try ^(?:[a-z0-9]+([,-]|$))(?:[a-z0-9]+\1?)*$

Maybe you want to allow hyphen or comma at the start/end of string? Like with ^(?!.*([-,])[^-,\n]*(?!\1)[,-])[-,]?[a-z0-9]+(?:[,-][a-z0-9]+)*[-,]?$ (demo, the \n is only for the demo purposes, btw)?

This question makes no sense and OP is unresponsive, voting to close.

Right, there are several things that are unclear: 1) how the pattern is used inside the code, 2) what exact requirements are in place.

It's as simple as it sounds. Either I want a hyphen or a comma delimited list as an input into a textbox on a GUI page for validation. So either it should be a - or something like this opl,yyytr,bbbn. I'm not sure what is so complicated about the requirements. And the regex expression that I put into my question above only validates (opl,yyytr,bbbn) but if this list of strings is replaced by - then the regex expression doesn't work.

@user2913184 - What do you mean by your question? It's BAgn's question.

It seems to me that you need ^[^,\-]+([,\-][^,\-]+)*$, but some positive and negative examples would be good. For example, it's not clear what opl,yyytr-bbbn should be.

You can use parentheses and a pipe character | to make a logical OR in regexes!
For example, (abc|def) would select any text that is either "abc" or "def".
In your case, I believe what you want would be ^(-|[-A-Za-z0-9]+(,[-A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$.

This one also matches -- or --- meaning more than one hyphen but I just want to match either a SINGLE - or a comma delimited list of strings

Well, since you've added the hyphen to your character sets, I assume whatever value is in the comma separated list could contain hyphens?
Right now, it's selecting "---" since that's effectively a comma-separated list with only one item in it.
If your data can't have hyphens in it, just remove them from the character sets and it will work: ^(-|[A-Za-z0-9]+(,[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$.
If your data can have hyphens, you can use a negative lookahead to make sure it's not just hyphens: ^(-|(?!-*$)[-A-Za-z0-9]+(,[-A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$
Both of those will match - but not ---.

@BAgn Does the comma-delimited list have to have at least one comma? Change the * to +. Then it will match ---,--- but not just ---

One possible problem with the regex in this solution is that it would not work in XML Schema regex, it is not compliant with POSIX BRE, either. We still do not know where OP uses the pattern.
